# The getter 'children' isn't defined for the class 'PageView'

Tags: list, flutter, widget

I am just out of ideas on how this is possible, but here's the code:

```
PageView widgetPageView = new PageView(children: <Widget>[],);

dataList.forEach((e){
  Leader c = Leader.fromJson(e);
  widgetPageView.children.add(*unimportant stings*); <--- Error here
});
```

The thing is that when I define PageView it has the "children" getter, while in the for loop it doesn't. Please help. The error itself is "The getter 'children' isn't defined for the class 'PageView'"

Answer (score 0):

```
final List<Widget> children = [];

PageView widgetPageView = PageView(
  children: children,
);

dataList.forEach((e) {
  Leader c = Leader.fromJson(e);
  children.add(Text('child 1'));
});
```